# Paragraphs being miscounted

Tags: java, text-files

So I want my program to count the number of paragraphs from a text file but unfortunately I end being 1 number off. I need the answer of 4 when I keep getting 5. Here is the text:

```
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in
Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal. 

Now   we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so
dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a
portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might
live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this. 

But,    in a larger sense, we can not dedicate -- we can not consecrate -- we can not hallow -- this ground.
The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add
or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget
what they did here. It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which
they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great
task remaining before us -- that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which
they gave the last full measure of devotion -- that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have
died in vain -- that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom -- and that government of
the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.



Abraham Lincoln
November 19, 1863
```

And here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the input file: ");
    input = kbd.nextLine();
    try
    {
        // Set up connection to the input file
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new FileReader(input));

        // Set up connection to an output file
        PrintWriter output=newPrintWriter(newFileOutputStream(input".txt"));

        // initialize the counter for the line numbers
        int lineNum = 0;
        int words = 0;
        int characters = 0;
        int paragraphs = 0;
        // as long as there are more lines left in the input file
        // read from the input file, and copy to the output file
        while (input1.hasNextLine())
            {
        // read a line from the input file
        String line;

        line = input1.nextLine();
        // copy the line to the output file, adding a
        // line number at the front of the line
        output.println(line + "\n");
        // increment the line counter
        lineNum++;
        //Section for counting the words
         boolean word = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                //checks for letters and counts as word till it finds a space then checks for a letter again.
                if (!Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i)) && !word) {

                    words++;
                    word = true;
                }
                else if (Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i)) && word){
                    word = false;

                }
            }   
            characters += line.length();
            paragraphs += getPara(line);
            }


        // close the files
        input1.close();
        output.close(); 
        System.out.println("Lines: " + lineNum);
        System.out.println("Words: " + words);
        System.out.println("Characters: " + ((characters)));
        System.out.println("Paragraphs: " + paragraphs);



    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("There was an error opening one of the files.");
    }

}

public static int getPara(String line){  
    int count = 0; 
    boolean p = false;

    if (line.isEmpty() && !p){
        count++;
        p = true;
    }
    else if (!line.isEmpty() && p){
        p = false;
    }

    return count;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code counts empty lines rather than paragraphs.  Stray empty lines in your input file will add to your paragraph count.

Assumptions and definitions are key in cases like this.  How is a paragraph defined in your requirements documentation? Can you assume that paragraphs will be a single line terminated by a newline or will you need to account for newlines within paragraphs?  If it's the former, all nonempty lines returned by `nextLine()` will be paragraphs.  If it's the latter, then you will need to add to your paragraph count only if an empty line or EOF follows a nonempty line.

In any case, you will be better served using language utilities like [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to count your words, unless you're required to do it manually.

Comment: a paragraph is a line followed by an empty line. the method does not read each line it only reads the first one